# How to get capybara chrome headless to open sweetalert2 modals for Rspec tests

Tags: selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, rspec-rails

I'm currently using

selenium-webdriver 3.141.0
chromedriver-helper 2.1.0

gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'sweet-alert2-rails'

With Rails 5.2

My Capybara setup:

```
RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test 
  end
  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do 
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end 
end
require "capybara-screenshot/rspec"

#Use the following to set the screen size for tests
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  [
    "headless",
    "window-size=1280x1280",
    "disable-gpu" # https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome
  ].each { |arg| options.add_argument(arg) }

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end
```

I run the following test:

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe 'deleting a proofread document using ajax', js: true do

      let(:job)  { create(:proofreading_job, title: 'Internal Job') }
      let(:user) { job.proofreader.user }

      it 'can delete a proofread document' do
        visit root_path
        click_on 'Login'
        fill_in  'Email', with: user.email
        fill_in  'Password', with: user.password
        click_on 'Sign In'
        click_on 'Dashboard'
        click_on 'Proofreading Jobs'
        click_on 'Current'
        click_on 'Internal Job'
        click_on 'Upload Proofread Document'
        attach_file(I18n.t('proofreader.proofread_document.upload'), Rails.root + 'spec/test_documents/proofread_document/1.docx' , make_visible: true)
        accept_alert do
           find_button('Upload', disabled: false).click
        end
        expect(page).to_not have_button('Delete')

     end
   end
 end
```

However the test fails with Rspec informing me that:

```
 Capybara::ModalNotFound:
   Unable to find modal dialog
```

However, I have manually used the webpage and the modal does show and work properly.

How can I get Capybara Selenium Chrome Headless Driver to open the modal in the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accept_alert` is for dealing with system modals (those the browser creates by default when calling `window.alert` that don't actually add elements to the page).  Sweetalert2 is a JS library that inserts elements to the page to create more stylish "modals".  You don't use `accept_alert` with those, you just interact with them as if they were any other HTML elements on the page.  That would mean something along the lines of

```
....
attach_file(...)
click_button('Upload', disabled: false) # Not sure why you're passing `disabled: false` here since that's the default
within('.swal2-actions') { click_button('the text of the button to accept the "modal"') }
expect(page)....
```

Update: As discovered in the comments - an additional cause of this issue was the assets not being compiled, in the OPs setup, so the JS wasn't firing at all. This would be immediately clear when running in non-headless mode and seeing that no "modal" was ever being displayed. The fix for that depends on what asset pipeline is being used and how it's configured, which goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I tried your solution and I get the error 'Unable to find visible css ".swal2-actions"'.  It's as if the modal is not being shown at all.  BTW I need to put disabled:false because the button is disabled until the user adds a file to upload.

Comment: @chell `disabled: false` is the default setting for `find_button`, passing it in will make no difference. As for `.swal2-actions` I took that class from the default examples shown at  https://sweetalert2.github.io/ - if you've customized anything then you'd have to change the class to match whatever you've customized to. If the modal isn't being shown at all  then you need to check the browser console for JS errors and fix them.

Comment: @chell Also are you sure the test type is set to :system - otherwise it would be running with rack_test which doesn't support any JS at all (and you might as well run in non-headless while debugging so you can see what's actually happening)

Comment: As per @ThomasWalpole suggestion I used non-headless to see what was happening. In deed there modal was not opening as it should. In environment/test.rb I turned of asset precompile and the modal opened in the test. So something with the way the assets are being compiled is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok I had to precompile my assets and now it works in test, development and production. Also what you told me about the accept_alert and interacting with the .swal2-actions was spot on. So if you could update your answer to include making sure the assets are precompiled properly then I can accept the answer.